# product flat data at magento 2 index error at setup:upgrade or at indexer:reset

Tags: magento, magento2

I had an error that took me hours to fix.
When running setup:upgrade at Magento 2, I got stuck at Running schema recurring...State for the same indexer already exists.

So, I figured out that flat catalog product has a index at "Processing".

I tried to run indexer:reset and all index was reseted, except the one I need, I got an "State for the same indexer already exists"

If I try running indexer again, I got a "Product Flat Data index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping."

Comment: Welcome to SO! If your intent is to show how you fixed a specific problem, please post the problem as a question ([see here for help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) and then answer your own question with the solution so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The unique solution that works for that very specific case is:

Log to your database

Run:

```sql
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE path = 'catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product';
```

This will disable the flat_catalog_product.

Then run this:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

and then setup:upgrade will work again such as all other index.